# hibernate search 6 updating elasticsearch index after entity update

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

I have a problem using elasticsearch with hibernate search 6. Let's assume we have this setup :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entityA")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Indexed(index = "entityA")
public class EntityA {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
  @GenericField
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  @KeywordField
  private String name;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(unique = true)
  @Cascade(value = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
  @IndexedEmbedded
  @IndexingDependency(reindexOnUpdate = ReindexOnUpdate.SHALLOW)
  private EntityB entityB;
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entityB")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class EntityB {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
  @GenericField
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  @KeywordField
  private String name;

  @OneToOne(cascade = {}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = EntityA.class)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
  @IndexingDependency(reindexOnUpdate = ReindexOnUpdate.DEFAULT)
  private EntityA entityA
```

}

When I first persist EntityA, that being the entity that is indexed, the EntityB is persisted in the elasticsearch index as a child of EntityA. This is ok. The problem appears when I directly edit EntityB and make changes to it, this changes are not propagated to the elasticsearch index. Is something that i am missing?

UPDATE 1

After @yrodiere answers, i made this changes :

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(unique = true)
@Cascade(value = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, 
CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
@IndexedEmbedded
@AssociationInverseSide(inversePath = @ObjectPath( 
@PropertyValue( 
propertyName = "entitya" ) ))
 private EntityB entityB;
```

The problem still persist. If i do something like this :

```
EntityB b = entityBRepository.findById(5051L).get();
b.setProperty("3333");
entityBRepository.save(b);
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem appears when I directly edit EntityB and make changes to it, this changes are not propagated to the elasticsearch index.

You explicitly instructed Hibernate Search to behave exactly that way:

```java
  @IndexingDependency(reindexOnUpdate = ReindexOnUpdate.SHALLOW)
  private EntityB entityB;
```

`reindexOnUpdate = ReindexOnUpdate.SHALLOW` means "reindex `EntityA` when the `entityB` property of `EntityA` changes, but not when a property of `EntityB` itself (e.g. its name) changes".

See [this section of the reference documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-reindexing-reindexonupdate-shallow).

I'm guessing you added that to get rid of an exception telling you that Hibernate Search was unable to find the inverse side of the association `EntityA.entityB`. In your case, it seems you should rather tell Hibernate Search what the inverse side of that association is. Either add a `mappedBy` to one side of the association (Warning: this will change your DB schema), or use `@AssociationInverseSide` (see [this section of the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-reindexing-associationinverseside)).